# Popular (single) imputation methods for ordinal variable

Tags: r, ordinal-data, monte-carlo, data-imputation

I am setting up a monte carlo simulation study in R for a comparison between several imputation methods for ordinal variables. So far, I am planning to use the following imputation methods:

Multiple imputation methods:

- Predictive Mean Matching with 'mice'
- Predictive Mean Matching with 'BaBooN'
- Proportional Odds Model (polr) with 'mice'

Single imputation methods:

- Hot Deck Nearest Neighbor with 'HotDeckImputation'

I expect that the Predictive Mean Matching algorithms of mice and BaBooN will show the best results. However, since I want to perform a comparison between several different methods, I am searching for some more popular imputation methods. I am especially searching for some popular single imputation methods, since I also want to show the difference between single and multiple imputation. The imputation literature focusses mainly on multiple imputation. Therefore it was difficult to find some popular single imputation methods.

What are the most popular single imputation methods for ordinal variables? In which R packages are they implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always had the impression, AMELIA, VIM, mice, are the most popular R imputation packages. (others may see this different)

VIM has two functions for single imputation of ordinal variables:
kNN and irmi

So maybe you want to try these.

Another approach for you:

Here are all CRAN R packages listed.
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/available_packages_by_name.html

You could search for the terms imputation / missing data and for the packages you find have a look at the documentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input! I already finished the project and in the end I implemented PMM with mice and BaBooN, polr with mice, Hot Deck Nearest Neighbor with HotDeckImputation, and Regression Imputation with VIM.

Comment: Sounds like a good choice. Also sounds interesting, maybe you can share the link if you have published the results.

Comment: I worked on the topic during a traineeship in a statistical office. Therefore I am not sure if I am allowed to publish the results. Overall PMM has shown the best results.